# Rearranging Annuity formula

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, finance, economics

Can someone please show me how this is rearranged/simplified from this: PV = CF[(1-(1+r)^-n)/r] to PV= CF(1/r)[1-(1/((1+r)^n)] with steps, will help me wrap my head around it.

Also, how does it go from the Sum of c/(1+r)^n to those formulas in the first place?

Note: PV is the present value, CF is cash flow, r is rate, and n is periods (for context).

I would appreciate any help! I can't find anything specific to the rearrangement for this online, and not sure what to search for...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first Term should be with  negative exponent: PV = CF[(1-(1+r)^(-n))/r]

Comment: Thank you callculus42! I've edited it. Are you possibly able to show me how the first formula simplifies/changes or how they are the same?

Comment: We have $(1+r)^{-n}=1/(1+r)^n$. And 1/r has been factored out. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's start with the first initial formula,

PV = CF [ (1 - ((1+r)^-n)) / r ]

We can first expand the numerator as such,

PV = CF [ (1/r) - (((1+r)^-n) * (1/r)) ]

Then factoring out (1/r),

PV = CF (1/r) [ 1 - ((1+r)^-n) ]

PV = CF (1/r) [ 1 - (1/((1+r)^-n)) ]

Comment: Thank you Nox Prixcz! I still don't understand why the 1 becomes (1/r), and the r becomes (1/r) when you change the sign from/to *, but nothing happens to the (1+r)^-n if you care to elaborate, but I do appreciate it! I can't upvote you get because I'm new, but I've clicked it anyway.